# Body responsive html css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

estoy construyendo una página con bootstrap y ya conseguí que el navbar y el footer sea responsive pero el body no sé bien como hacerlo. al igual que tengo un navegador lateral que acompaña al usuario. Acá les muestro el código del html

```
<div class="container-fluid fondoblanco shadow-lg col-8">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 100px;">
                <img
                    class="logo"
                    align="center"
                    src="img/index/quienesSomos.png"
                    alt="logo"
                    style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="row text-light jumbotron shadow"
                style="background-color: #1c2a48;"
            >
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="p-5">
                        <h2 class="" align="left">¿Qué es Bitonoff?</h2>
                        <p class="text-justify parrafo">
                            Grupo Bitonoff C.A les Ofrece Las mejores ofertas en curso.
                            Nuestros certificados son <b>100% apostillables</b>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="p-5">
                        <h2 class="" align="left">Lorem</h2>
                        <p class="text-justify parrafo">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore
                            totam consequatur architecto vero dolor magni fugiat dolorem
                            repudiandae voluptatem. Minus nam accusamus rem facilis,
                            aspernatur placeat enim alias aliquid iste.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container py-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col tarjetacentro">
                        <div class="card shadow-lg redounded" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img
                                class="card-img-top"
                                src="img/index/muestra/marcha.jpg"
                                alt="Imagen Muestra"
                            />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Día del músico</h5>
                                <p class="card-text text-center">
                                    Marcha día del músico 2019
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col tarjetacentro">
                        <div class="card shadow-lg redounded" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img
                                class="card-img-top"
                                src="img/index/muestra/diploma.jpg"
                                alt="Imagen Muestra"
                            />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Diploma</h5>
                                <p class="card-text text-center">
                                    Entrega de Diploma "Pedro Gual"
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-lg redounded" style="width: 13rem;">
                            <img
                                class="card-img-top"
                                src="img/index/muestra/orquesta.jpg"
                                alt="Imagen Muestra"
                            />
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-center">Orquesta Caripito</h5>
                                <p class="card-text text-center">
                                    Orquesta sinfónica Infantil
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container py-5 experiencia">
                <h2 class="titulo text-center">
                    <b>
                        Con más de 10 años de experiencia
                    </b>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y el navegador lateral es así

```
<div class="social">
            <ul class="shadow-lg rounded">
                <li class="">
                    <a class="" href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img
                            src="img/redes/facebookF.svg"
                            alt="facebook"
                            width="30"
                            height="40"
                        />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="" href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img
                            src="img/redes/twitterF.svg"
                            alt="twitter"
                            width="30"
                            height="40"
                        />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a class="" href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
                        <img
                            src="img/redes/instagramF.svg"
                            alt="instagram"
                            width="30"
                            height="40"
                        />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Mi duda es... ¿Cómo hago que sea responsive y me gustaría aprender ya que este solo es el index de la página. También en la barra lateral cómo haría? se quedaría fija ahí o hay una forma para hacerla también responsive? así se ve mi barra lateral [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

las clases de bootstrap sobre las columnas, para hacerlas responsivas tienes que agregar por ejemplo del la siguiente manera.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="p-5">
        <h2 class="" align="left">¿Qué es Bitonoff?</h2>
        <p class="text-justify parrafo">
            Grupo Bitonoff C.A les Ofrece Las mejores ofertas en curso.
            Nuestros certificados sonf <b>100% apostillables</b>.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="p-5">
        <h2 class="" align="left">¿Qué es Bitonoff?</h2>
        <p class="text-justify parrafo">
            Grupo Bitonoff C.A les Ofrece Las mejores ofertas en curso.
            Nuestros certificados sonf <b>100% apostillables</b>.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="p-5">
        <h2 class="" align="left">¿Qué es Bitonoff?</h2>
        <p class="text-justify parrafo">
            Grupo Bitonoff C.A les Ofrece Las mejores ofertas en curso.
            Nuestros certificados sonf <b>100% apostillables</b>.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

En este ejemplo

- para una pantalla superior a 1200px tendras en una fila a las tres columnas
- para una pantalla superior a 768px tendras en una dos columnas en una fila, y el tercero bajara a la siguiente fila
- para una pantalla por debajo de 768px tendras en la primera fila a la columna 1, y por debajo las dos columnas

En [Boostrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) el sistema de grillas esta dividada en 12columnas.
donde

- col-12, col-sm-12... .- ocupan las doce columnas, indica que tu articulo estara en una sola fila
- col-6, col-md-6... .- ocupan 6 columnas, indica que en una fila podran caber 2 articulos
- col-4, col-md-4... .- ocupan 4 columnas, indica que en una fila podran caber 3 articulos
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]